# CakePHP 2.6: validation domain with plugin

Tags: cakephp, internationalization, cakephp-model, cakephp-2.6

I have a plugin. Whitin my plugin models:

```
public $validationDomain = 'validation_my_plugin';
```

The file `APP/Plugin/MyPlugin/Locale/ita/LC_MESSAGES/validation_my_plugin.po` exists and it's right.
Still not working. Yet the rest of the plugin works properly, the model validation is the only one not working.

I noticed that if I copy the `.po` file in my APP (`APP/Locale/ita/LC_MESSAGES/validation_my_plugin.po`) then this works and the validation messages are correctly translated.

Why does this happen? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Did it work in CakePHP < 2.6? Maybe it has something todo with https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/5c5fb59

Comment: @tersmitten I tried with 2.5.6 and 2.4.8 versions, but it looks the same.